# $\mu^* \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\right) = 0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let us have a fixed interval $I_0=[a,b]$ and let $A$ be a subset of $I_0.$
Let $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of subsets of $I_0$ s.t $\mu^* (A_n)$ (outer measure) is 0 for all natural $n$.
How to prove that $$\mu^* \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\right) = 0$$

without using the fact that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ is measurable?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you prove/use the fact that outer measure of union of $A_n$ is bounded by sum of outer measures of $A_n$ ?

Comment: @MarcinŁoś isn't that one of the defining properties of an outer measure?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Use the $\sigma-$subadditivy and you obtain:
$$
0 \leq \mu^*(\bigcup A_n) \leq \sum \mu^*(A_n)
$$